# Apple music User Token

Tags: ios, swift, apple-musickit

I am trying to get user token with **requestUserToken** method.I have also generated Developer token but it will return error like **(SKErrorDomain error 7.)** Please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby to get the develop token, it's the problem. Try to use python. This is my answer in another problem

It is the problem of develop token. I fixed it by using https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator. At the beginning, i use another ruby generator to get develop token. I test ok by using curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer [developer token]' "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs/203709340", but also get (SKErrorDomain error 7.) in sample code. Now it is ok. The ruby generator doesn’t work with requesting user tokens:https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator/issues/4

Comment: Please add details to this answer instead of linking to the other one. While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I am using the python generator but am still getting the same error Error code domain = 7